# contains pyspark SQL: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark 2.0.1,

```
 df.show()
+--------+------+---+-----+-----+----+
|Survived|Pclass|Sex|SibSp|Parch|Fare|
+--------+------+---+-----+-----+----+
|     0.0|   3.0|1.0|  1.0|  0.0| 7.3|
|     1.0|   1.0|0.0|  1.0|  0.0|71.3|
|     1.0|   3.0|0.0|  0.0|  0.0| 7.9|
|     1.0|   1.0|0.0|  1.0|  0.0|53.1|
|     0.0|   3.0|1.0|  0.0|  0.0| 8.1|
|     0.0|   3.0|1.0|  0.0|  0.0| 8.5|
|     0.0|   1.0|1.0|  0.0|  0.0|51.9|
```

I have a data frame and I want to add a new column to df using withColumn and value of new column is base on other column value. I used something like this:

```
>>> dfnew = df.withColumn('AddCol' , when(df.Pclass.contains('3.0'),'three').otherwise('notthree'))
```

It is giving an error

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

can any help how to over come this error.

Answer (score 10):

Its because you are trying to apply the function `contains` to the column. The function `contains` does not exist in pyspark. You should try `like`. Try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("AddCol",F.when(F.col("Pclass").like("3"),"three").otherwise("notthree"))
```

Or if you just want it to be exactly the number `3` you should do:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# If the column Pclass is numeric
df = df.withColumn("AddCol",F.when(F.col("Pclass") == F.lit(3),"three").otherwise("notthree"))

# If the column Pclass is string
df = df.withColumn("AddCol",F.when(F.col("Pclass") == F.lit("3"),"three").otherwise("notthree"))
```

Comment: The function `contains` is described in the documentation without any _New in version X.X_ warning [as seen here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.contains).  Any idea why is not available?

Comment: In this case, the user was using pyspark 2.0.1, in wich contains is not available. Check your pyspark version, because contains is only available from 2.2 and above. Cheers.